# Remove parent of an UIElement in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, uielement

I have an object of an `UIElement`, how  can I remove the parent of it?

I saw that there is not setter for parent property of an `UIElement`.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

EDIT :

```
 protected FrameworkElement Content
        {
            get { return this.content; }
            set
            {
                if ((this.content != null) && (this.Children.Contains(this.content)
== true))
                    this.Children.Remove(this.content);
                this.content = value;
                if ((this.content != null) && (this.Children.Contains(this.content)
== false))
                {
                    this.Children.Add(this.content); // here i get error Element is already an child of another
                }

                this.InvalidateMeasure();
                this.InvalidateArrange();
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you give an example? Do you want to remove a child element from its parent from within the child code? This usually stumps people.

Comment: i get an object of an ui element say from somewhere an i want to insert this object in an panel but as that ui element already has parent set , is causing problem for me.

Comment: You want to **insert** the element **into** a panel. Then this element becomes a **child **. You would do `panel.Children.Add(yourelement);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`UIElement.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee435441.aspx) just returns the Parent as a `UIElement`. You can cast it to the right element if you **know** what the parent is. Lets say you have a parent this IS a `StackPanel`

```
 StackPanel parent = myelement.Parent as StackPanel;
 parent.Children.Remove(myelement);//removes your element from its parent.
```